# Expand elements of array split by comma

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have the following array:

```
const arr = [ 'a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i' ];
```

I want to get to

```
[ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i' ]
```

I am currently using reduce https://jsbin.com/xejedexada/edit?js,console

```
arr.reduce((a,c) => (typeof a == 'object' ? a : a.split(',')).concat(c.split(',')));
```

But I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: In a future js version itll be `arr.flatMap(el => el.split(","));`

Comment: Nice @JonasWilms thanks for that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reduce method and `split` to split the string by comma

```js
let m = ['a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i'];

let x = m.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  acc.push(...curr.split(','))
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(x)
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is the best solution. I had also come up with a version using push, but had overlooked the initial value arg, which simplifies it a lot.  Going to accept your answer.

Comment: My final version based on your answer was `arr.reduce((a, c) => (a.push(...c.split(',')),a), [])`

Comment: Why not `arr.reduce((acc, el) => acc.concat(el.split(",")), [])` ?

Comment: Because concat is needlessly creating copies of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.join()` and `.split()` methods:

```js
const arr = [ 'a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i' ];

const result = arr.join().split(",");

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**References:**

- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need reduce for that just use `join(',')` and `split(',')`:

```js
const arr = [ 'a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i' ];
var res = arr.join(',').split(',');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

simply `concat` the splited subarray

```js
const arr = [ 'a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i' ];
console.log( [].concat(...arr.map(a=>a.split(','))) )
```